# Can't test Apollo GraphQL query's loading state

Tags: react-native, testing, graphql, apollo

guys. I have a query that gets data from backend, while query didn't get data I'm showing '...Loading' text. Now I want to test it, but I can't. Test's logic is: if loading state is true, check if we have '...Loading' text.

Here is my query:

```
const [getCards, { data: cardsData, error: cardsError, loading: cardsLoading }] = useLazyQuery(
  GET_LIST,
  {
    fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
  }
);
```

Here is my check of loading state:

```
if (cardsLoading) {
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
      }}
    >
      <Text>...Loading</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

And finally here is my test:

```
const getCardsMock = [
  {
    request: {
      query: GET_LIST,
    },
    result: {
      cards: {
        id: 0,
        name: 'card',
      },
    }
  },
];

it('Loading state test', async () => {
  const component = renderer.create(
    <MockedProvider mocks={getCardsMock} addTypename={false}>
      <HomeViewApollo />
    </MockedProvider>
  );

  const tree = component.toJSON();
  expect(tree.children).toContain('...Loading');
});
```

After running test I got an error telling me that expected value isn't equal to received value. Received value is array with component, that I render, if loading is done.
I'm not sure but looks like that component's loading state never changes during the test. Do you have an idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rewrote test like that

```
  it('Loading state test', async () => {
    let wrapper = render(
      <MockedProvider mocks={[getCardsMock]} addTypename={false}>
        <HomeViewApollo />
      </MockedProvider>
    );
    await waitFor(() => [
      expect(wrapper.queryByTestId('loadingIndicator')).toBeTruthy()
    ]);
  });
```

Now it works.